# Как проверить, что строка1 является частью строки2 и занимает определенную позицию

Tags: c++, строки

Нужно проверить, что строка1 - это часть строки2, и при этом она занимает определенную позицию. Ну т е, примерно так:

```
const string str1 = "ab";
const string str2 = "baby";
const unsigned int start = 1;
const unsigned int end = 2;
```

Есть мысль такая - вытащить буквы по индексам, сделать слово и его проверить. Есть мысль использовать string.find(), только вот нельзя по нему проверить по конкретной позиции (ну или я не знаю, как это сделать). Догадываюсь насчет того, как решить проблему, но желаю услышать ответы более опытных программистов, ибо выбирать отдельные буквы - ну, мне кажется, такое себе - может, есть более быстрый и грамотный способ?

Comment: `str2.substr(start, end - start + 1) == str1`

Comment: Что такое `end`? `start + str1.size() - 1` или что-то другое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD: есть rfind():

```
size_t string.rfind(const string str, size_t pos);
```